# Can we use a windows service for a web application which can trigger a mail on specific date and time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I am creating a web application which will trigger a mail but the mail will be trigger on specific date and time(with the help of web application).

I am not understanding that how can I achieve this in web application.

Does windows service is the solution for this ?

Please let me know which is the best solution and how do I do this using c# code?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this, you will need

1. Database
2. Windows Service
3. Web application

First create a database which is the same for your application and service.

Create a UI in your web application which sets the date and time of the mail to be sent. Then save this data in the database.

Now, in the windows service (assuming you know windows services), just check the date and time from the database and send the mail accordingly.

To create a windows service you may find these links useful

1. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Automatically-send-emails-daily-at-specific-time-using-Windows-Service-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx
2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/create-windows-service-and-send-mail-daily-on-fixed-time-usi575/

Just get the time from your database and check against that time and you will have a dynamic service.

Comment: Your Welcome.. glad to be of help @Macwin

Answer (score 3):

You can use FluentScheduler.

```
Install-Package FluentScheduler
```

Then you can add the code like below:

```
Schedule(() =>
    {
        //mailingJob or anything else you want to do
    }).ToRunOnceAt(yourSpecificDateTime);
```

For more info go to https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler